# putting data in other table after five years

Tags: php, database

I need to pick to the list of patients who are not having they follow up check ups after five years and save it to other table. this process will do when i load the list of the patients,but the code that i have didn't work. Please help me

```
//this is my code for getting the date of the patient last check up

<?php
include('connect.php');
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT date as date FROM tblnpatient"); 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) { 
$dt = $row['date']; 
}

?>
```

this is my code for putting the records after five years in the new table

```
<script>
function arch()
{ var c ='<?php echo $dt; ?>';
var cc= c.getFullYear
var dd= new date();
var cd = dd.getFullYear();
var bb = cd - cc;

if(bb > 5 || (bb == 5)) {
<?php
include('connect.php');
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblnpatient"); 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) { 
$pnum=$row['pnum'];
$pname=$row['pname'];
$addr=$row['addr'];
$bdate=$row['bdate'];
$age=$row['age'];
$sex=$row['sex'];
$civil=$row['civil'];
$cont=$row['cont'];
$fname=$row['fname'];
$mname=$row['mname'];
$sname=$row['sname'];
$complaints=$row['complaints'];
$bp=$row['bp'];
$bt=$row['bt'];
$weight=$row['weight'];
$date=$row['date'];

$update=mysql_query("INSERT INTO tblarch(pnum, pname, addr, bdate, cont, fname, mname,     sname, sex, civil, age, bp, bt, weight, complaints, date)
   VALUES('$pnum','$pname','$addr','$bdate','$cont','$fname','$mname','$sname','$sex','$civil','$age','$bp','$bt','$weight','$complaints','$date')");

        exit();}
 ?>
```

}

Comment: As a side note, you really shouldn't be using `mysql_*` queries, as they have been deprecated

Comment: This code is bad and needs to be rewritten

Comment: what is type of your coloumn `date`

Comment: When you do not expect a result-set (when you use INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE), you should use `mysql_unbuffered_query()` instead of `mysql_query()`

Comment: Why not do this in SQL directly without PHP?

Answer (score 0):

You can change your query to check for the 5 year time frame quite easily.

```
SELECT date as date FROM tblnpatient WHERE date <= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 5 YEAR);
```

[Mysql Date_Sub doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub)

This means you can now just INSERT the data into your new table without any of the Javascript code for checking the date.

Furthermore you can also remove the need for any PHP code if the two tables are similar enough.

Example:

```
INSERT INTO tblarch (pnum, pname, addr, bdate, cont, fname, mname, sname, sex, civil, age, bp, bt, weight, complaints, date) 
SELECT (pnum, pname, addr, bdate, cont, fname, mname, sname, sex, civil, age, bp, bt, weight, complaints, date) 
FROM tblnpatient WHERE date <= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 5 YEAR);
```

Comment: it does not saving in tblarch when i load it